# ngx datatable Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using ngx datatable with angular 4. When I open a model in ngx datatable column on click event. Model open works fine but showing the error in console.
Error is below:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'datatable-body-cell sort-active active'. Current value: 'datatable-body-cell sort-active'.
```

Comment: read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: This question is not entirely duplicated. The root reason is the same but it is not obvious since the way ngx-datatable handle it.

Comment: short answer: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/issues/721, 
onActive(event) {
        (event.type === 'click') && event.cellElement.blur();
}